# Pushing changes from a new machine to a github repository

Tags: git, github, push, git-push

1. I had a git repository cloned (Machine1/.../Github/GitM1) on Machine 1 from my Github repository Git1.
2. I copied the GitM1 folder (complete) on Machine 2.
3. I ran the project (Machine2/.../Github/GitM1) on Machine 2 and made changes (~1MB) with nothing related to git (even git not installed)
4. Now, I want to commit these changes to my Github repository Git1.
5. How to do this (I prefer to do this via SSH key route)?

Thanks.

Edit : on using Jonathan's answer : I am getting this :

[On pushing to git repository](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbWOw.png)

On doing a pull asks me remove files (=50+) for merging. I am not sure if this is going in right direction.

Answer (score 0):

On the "Machine2" copy of the repository...

First, add a remote to GitHub:

```
git remote add github _github url_
```

Next, push the change to GitHub:

```
git push github master
```

If on Machine2 you want the default remote to be GitHub (so you can just use "origin" rather than "github"), let's clobber any existing origin like this:

```
git remote remove origin
git remote add github _github url_
```

See "[Working with remotes](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes)"

EDIT:

The "*update were rejected...*" error is because your master branch is behind the master branch on GitHub. Basically...you need to update your master branch.

There are several ways to do this, but a good way would be to rebase your changes on top of the changes on GitHub.

Follow these steps (assuming you set the *github* remote as above):

```
git fetch github
git rebase github/master
```

If there are any code-conflicts Git will tell you. Resolve the conflicts by editing the files and follow Git's instructions.

When you are done with these steps perform the push.

Comment: @user3363723 Ok, gotcha. Let me know if that works for you

Comment: @user3363723 since it looks like you made your "origin" point to GitHub (good move) use "origin" in those commands, rather than "github"